# Sync Outlook Contacts in Active Directory

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

We have a large number of users in an active directory on our server. We need to keep all users up to date with current employee contacts and email addresses that can change sometimes as many as 3-4 times a month. We get these updated contacts as a .pst file and then spend hours each time manually updating contacts by logging in to each user and importing that .pst from the network.

Is there an easier, more efficient way to use this .pst file to update and distribute contacts across our active directory?  Better yet, is there a way to update a centrally located .pst file and have all the users outlook accounts auto-sync with that file?

(Exchange isn't an option unfortunately as management vetoed it for some reason)

Comment: What do you currently use as your email server?

Comment: We user CMail as a locally hosted email server

Comment: It sounds like Exchange would work better for you but that might not be an option.

Answer (score 0):

According to this PDF: `http://59.165.134.98/chowgule/newcmail.pdf` - CMAIL has the ability to do Shared Address Books, so you might start there...

Otherwise, my suggestion would be to look into Outlook Business Contact Manager from Microsoft.  It's usually a free download, depending on the version of Office you are running, and can provide shared contacts and so much more if you want it to.  See here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/download-and-install-business-contact-manager-for-outlook-HA010262563.aspx

Comment: That does seem to be what I need, however I cant find it. We have an installation file of Office 2007 that was installed on the server years ago and does not seem to have Business Contact Manager in it. I cant seem to find any info on where to get it or how to add it to our current installation.

Comment: Seems the links are not working kindly update the links,
 thanks